# Direct product, homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Prove (G1 x G2)/(K1 x K2) is isomorphic to G1/K1 x G2/K2.

Attempt:
First,  we need to show a homomorphism exists, such that f : G1 x G2 → G1/K1 x G2/K2.
Second, we need to verify Imf = G1/K1 x G2/K2. 
Last, we need to verify Kerf = K1 x K2.

Then, I have define a homomorphism such that f[(g1, g2)] = (g1k1, g2k2), where g1,g2 are elements in G1 x G2, and k1,k2 are elements in K1 x K2. 
Then we need to show f[(g1,g2)(g1',g2')] = f[(g1,g2)]f[(g1',g2')]. 
So, f[(g1,g2)(g1',g2')] = [(g1k1, g2k2)][(g1'k1, g2'k2)] = [(g1g1'k1, g2g2'k2)] = g1g1'k1 x g2g2'k2 = G/K1 x G2/K2.

Can anyone please help me verify this is a good defined homomorphism.
I am confused because of the direct product part. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your homomorphism (as it is written now) does not even appear to have the appropriate domain and codomain. You'd like to map an element of $(G_1 \times G_2) / (K_1 \times K_2)$ to an element of $G_1 / K_1 \times G_2 / K_2$. What do elements of these two groups look like?

They should look like *cosets*. Elements of the quotient group $(G_1 \times G_2) / (K_1 \times K_1)$ are of the form $(g_1,g_2)(K_1\times K_2)$; they should not be written merely using their coset representatives from the group $G_1 \times G_2$. It is important that you have some grasp of the objects you are mapping between before you try to write out this mapping.

EDIT: The *domain* and *codomain* of a function $f$ are the sets that function maps *from* and *into*, respectively. If your goal is to write a homomorphism (which is a special kind of function) between two sets (which in your case happen to be groups), then you will need to make sure that your function takes in elements of the former set and yields elements of the latter. None of your attempts (either in the question or in comments) has satisfied this. You have not even defined a function between the correct sets, much less a well-defined homomorphism!

Comment: A correspondence between things that look like $(g_1, g_2)(K_1\times K_2)$ and things that looks like $(h_1 K_1, h_2 K_2)$, where $g_1,h_1\in G_1$, and $g_2,h_2\in G_2$.

Comment: Notice that I am using capital letters to denote groups; your use of lower-case $k_1$ and $k_2$ seems to me to be evidence of misunderstanding.

Comment: So for example: f[(g1,g2)] = (g1,g2)(K1 x K2). Then f[(g1,g2)]*f[(g1', g2')] = (g1,g2)(K1x K2)*(g1', g2')(K1 xK2) = (g1g1', g2g2')(K1 x K2)? Is this correct?

Comment: $f$ is meant to be your homomorphism, right? What are the domain and codomain of the $f$ that you've just written?

Comment: Yes, there is no restriction. I don't know, I would say it could be any elements